Combination of two Mono
I'm using Spring Cloud Filter and inside it i have two Mono:
Mono<ResponseEntity> firstMono = sender.send(request);
Mono<Void> secondMono = chain.filter(exchange)
What should the code do:
if response from 1st mono or response from second mono is OK -
exchange.getResponse().setStatus(200);
return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
if error from both mono -
exhange.getResponse().setStatus(500); 
return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
How to do it correctly?
